# Adding polygon attribute to a gdb raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, file-geodatabase

I am working with the gSSURGO soil database which has many tables with data and one raster file. I managed to join the tables to the raster, so now I click on my map and can see all raster attributes.

I also have a polygon layer with property code and would like to add this code as a column to my raster table. I tried to convert the polygon to a raster, but am not able to link both raster tables because I do not have a common field. Then I tried to extract the raster cells using the polygons as a mask, but am again unable to link the remaining records to the polygons.

How can the information on multiple gdb rasters be linked to the data of a polygon layer?

Comment: I can see a couple of issues with this. If you're trying to get a property code as an attribute of the soils raster, you can't really because the soils areas don't match up with the property boundaries and a single soils area may be covered by multiple properties. You run into a similar issue going the other direction, getting soils as a property of a polygon. You could vectorize the soils raster and then union those polygons with the properties to get a new set of polys that have both attributes. But I'm not clear on what your end goal is or what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'property' - attribute or parcel of land? Note that in a raster attribute table, the rows are for each *value* in the raster and said attributes apply to *all* cells with that value. If your polygons match the areas of a particular cell value and the code attribute applies to all those areas (not unique features/polygons) then what you ask might make sense.

Comment: I thought that the attribute table would give a value for each pixel. Thanks for clarifying that it is not like that. I was able to solve my problem with the gSSURGO database however, since the downloaded gdb files have a shapefile (that I had not seen before), besides the raster. So I was able to do a normal intersection between two shapefiles.